# How to remove the selectionIndicatorImage for the middle UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I'm using the custom `UITabBarItem` image for the middle item, so I have to make an `UIImage` for selectionIndicatorImage. 
According to this answer [Same question as mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14606940/2842382) I've made the code.

### Code

```
UIStoryboard *iPhoneSB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
UITabBarController *tbc = [iPhoneSB instantiateInitialViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = tbc;
tbc.delegate = self;

tbc.selectedIndex = 2;

UITabBar *tb = tbc.tabBar;

NSArray *items = tb.items;
for (UITabBarItem *tbi in items) {
  UIImage *image = tbi.image;
  tbi.selectedImage = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
  tbi.image = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
}
[tbc.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected-tabbar-bg.png"]];
```

And the delegate method:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex==2) {
        [tabBarController.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:nil];
    } else {
        [tabBarController.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected-tabbar-bg.png"]];
    }
}
```

It works, thanks to the answer. But there is some issue. `selectionIndicatorImage` is still nil after the first touch inside any `UITabBarItem` (sure except the middle).

**For example:**

On the app launch third UITabBar is selected. Touch at first item - selectionIndicatorImage works good (first item became selected). Touch at third item (particular item) - there is no selectionIndicator (it's good). But after that if I touch for example first - there is no selectionIndicator too. 
It appears if I touch second after that.
 Where I was wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you check that put break point in didSelect and touch the first tab then check whether the break point comes first or the selection image appears first?

Comment: I need to check that the delegate method get called before the selection image appears or after the selection image appears?

Comment: Can you check that? Please put break point and check it

Comment: @jai Oh, sorry. If I put the breakpoint before if (tabBarController.selectedIndex==2) (in delegate method) There is no selectionIndicatorImage. Delegate method is the first. If I put the point in the end of the method - there is the same situation.

Comment: Put logs in your delegate methods and also check that in your project that your are setting selectionIndicatorImage as nill

Comment: - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
   if(tabBarController.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage == nil)                          
 NSLog("Starting point delegate: Selection indicator image is nill"); 
   else
 NSLog("Ending Point Of delegate: Selection indicator image is available");

Comment: if (tabBarController.selectedIndex==2) {
        [tabBarController.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:nil];
    } else {
        [tabBarController.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected-tabbar-bg.png"]];
    }
   if(tabBarController.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage == nil)                          
 NSLog("Starting point Of delegate: Selection indicator image is nill"); 
   else
 NSLog("End point Of delegate: Selection indicator image is available"); 
}

Comment: `if(tabBarController.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage == nil)
        [tabBarController.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected-tabbar-bg.png"]];` and it works. Add this as an answer and I'll accept it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put logs in your delegate methods and also check that in your project, your are setting selectionIndicatorImage as nil.

```
 - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController { 

 if(tabBarController.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage == nil)
     NSLog("Starting point delegate: Selection indicator image is nill");
 else 
     NSLog("Starting Point Of delegate: Selection indicator image is available");

 if (tabBarController.selectedIndex==2) {
     [tabBarController.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:nil];
 } else {
     [tabBarController.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected-tabbar-bg.png"]];
 } 

 if(tabBarController.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage == nil)
     NSLog("Ending point delegate: Selection indicator image is nill");
 else 
     NSLog("Ending Point Of delegate: Selection indicator image is available");
   }
```